# Parallelized MATLAB code takes significantly longer time than serial.

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, mle

I am wanting to parallelize some MATLAB code that does some parameter fitting using MATLAB's `mle` routine. My reason for parallelization is that I want to execute the `mle` routine for multiple different guesses on the same data set.

Initial simulations show that the parallelized code takes anywhere from 200-400 seconds longer than the serial version (~500 seconds) depending on what data set I fit (to time, I just `tic` and `toc` at the beginning and end of my code). Am I using `parfor` incorrectly?

```
tic    
mitdata;  % load data
data=dmso; % take the 'DMSO' column data

num=length(data);

mm=linspace(.1, 1, 2)'; % mean values
vv=linspace(.1, 2, 2)'; % variance values
N=length(mm);
n=length(vv);

% get all combinations of the initial parameter guesses I want to try
pp = cell(N, n);
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:n
        pp{(i-1)*N+j} = [mm(i), vv(j)];
    end
end

temp = nchoosek([1:N*n, 1:N*n], 2); 
temp = sort(temp, 2); 
idx = unique(temp, 'rows'); 

P = zeros(length(idx),4);
for ii = 1:length(idx)
    P(ii,:) = [pp{idx(ii,1)},pp{idx(ii,2)}];
end

Pcell = num2cell(P);  % convert P to cell so that it's easier to assign parameter values for initial guess
options = statset('MaxIter',10000, 'MaxFunEvals',10000);

pd = zeros(length(P),4);   % space for best fit parameters
ld = NaN*ones(length(P),1);  % space for likelihood values


parfor i=1:length(P)
    [m1,v1,m2,v2] = Pcell{i,:};
    x0 = [m1,v1,m2,v2];  % initial guess
    [p,conf1]=mle(data,'pdf',@convolv_2invG,'start',x0, 'upperbound', [Inf Inf Inf Inf],'lowerbound',[0 0 0 0],'options',options)
    pd(i,:)=p;  % get best fit parameters from MLE
    l=convolv_2invG(data,p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4));  % use best fit parameters to evaluate pdf
    l=sum(log(l));
    if l<0
        ld(i)=l;  % store likelihood values
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: What is `length(P)`, and what are the sizes of some of the other variables you are using in the `parfor` loop? There is overhead in working out which iterations of the loop get sent to which cores, and then again getting the results back. You might also be moving lots of data around which will also slow things down. It's hard to be specific without a bit more information.

Comment: `length(P) = 10, size(pd) = 10 4, size(ld) = 10 1`

I have anywhere from 300-400 data points depending on what data set I fit.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable problem for parallelisation, not too many iterations so less overhead. What is your computer spec and how are you setting up the `matlabpool`?

Comment: And have you tried profiling your code to see which lines are taking the most time?

Comment: Quadcore 4.5ghz. I don't do anything to set up `matlabpool` - I just run the code and it let it go. I haven't profiled it, but I know the code is taking 99% of it's time calculating the best fit parameters with `[p,conf1]=mle(data,'pdf',@convolv_2invG,'start',x0, 'upperbound', [Inf Inf Inf Inf],'lowerbound',[0 0 0 0],'options',options)
    pd(i,:)=p;  % get best fit parameters from MLE`

Comment: I ran the MATLAB profiler. Here are some of the results:

mle: 10 calls, 2882.771s total time, 0.001s self time.

convolv_2invG: 29747 calls, 2877.891s total time, 118.767s self time.

fminsearch: 10 calls, 2860.781s total time, 1.802s self time.

stats\private\mlecustom>llf_pdfcdf: 33832 calls, 2858.977s total time, 2.634s self time.

conv: 29747 calls, 2740.540s total time, 2740.540s self time.

Hopefully that information is useful.

Comment: These profile times are for when the code is ran in serial by the way.

Comment: That means the bulk of the time is being used by `conv`, inside `mle`. I don't know why parallelisation isn't helping, unless `conv` has support for multithreading, which I'm not sure about. Sorry I can't help.